# XCode 7 project renamed results in 'Cannot import module being compiled' error in XCTestCase

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

After renaming my project from 'Triangles' to 'TriX', I have the described problem: 'Cannot import module being compiled' error in XCTestCase on line

```
@testable import TriX
```

Project is in Swift 2

Here is a screenshot of Build Settings Packaging section

[image]

Any ideas what can be done to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for your test case is somehow in the module TriX. Your project should have (at least) two targets: TriX, the module under test and something like TriXTests the tests for that module. Your test case should only be in the second module, not the first.

Comment: I see, the Test module was somehow renamed to have the same name as the original module. I now fixed it. Thanks!